# Clubbing two SQL statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables named table1 and table2.

Table1 has mapping with name and table1_id.

Table2 has mapping with table2_id and table1_id.

Now I want all the table2_ids which has table1_id1 but not table1_id2 where table1_id1 and table2_id2 are values.

and insert the above table2_ids with table1_id2 which makes if you execute above query it returns '0' number of rows.

Two sql statements that I have

```
select table2_id from table2 where table2.table1_id = 
 (select table1_id from table1 where table1.name = 'name1')
minus 
select table2_id from table2 where table2.table1_id = 
 (select table1_id from table1 where table1.name = 'name2')
```

Now run multiple insert into statements for all the above table2_ids as

```
 Insert into table2 values (table2_id, 
 (select table1_id from table1 
 where table1.name = 'name2'))
```

My problem statment is to club above this to single sql.

Example:

Table1

```
r1name r1id
r2name r2id
```

Table2

```
l1id r1id
l1id r2id
l2id r1id
l3id r1id
```

If I execute the first sql command with inputs for name as r1name and r2name respectively, I would get the output as "l2id,l3id" since l1id is mapped with r1id and r2id both and "l2id","l3id" is mapped with only "r1id".

Output after 1st sql statement execution:

```
l2id
l3id
```

Now I want insert a row into table2 with (l2id, r2id) and (l2id, r2id)

Output after 2 "insert" statements execution in table2

```
 l1id r1id
 l1id r2id
 l2id r1id
 l3id r1id
 l2id r2id
 l3id r3id.
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please explain it in simple form and example what exactly you need.. Also one more question - Can you have multiple entries against one table1 id in table 2?

Comment: I added example for your reference

Comment: Your question is still not clear, where did "r3id" come from? It was not in any table before.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (table2_id, table1_id)
SELECT table2_id, 'name2'
FROM table2
WHERE table2_id IN 
   (SELECT table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = 'name1')
AND table2_id NOT IN 
   (SELECT table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = 'name2');
```